# What book describes consuming vials of vampire blood to pseudo-Rage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, product-identification

I know I've ran across this in one of my 3.5 books recently and I cant remember the book or much about it, and am having trouble re-locating this. There was an entry towards the front of the book for a vial of vampiric blood. It gave similar stats as a barbarians rage but you were also considered under the control of the vampire while its effects lasted.

About the book: If i recall correctly, the book was focused more on monsters; but not the monster manual. I believe the passage where it talked about the vials was also talking about how a vampire could make a human its servant without changing it to a spawn or charming it. I really cant recall much about the book itself...  i believe it was in one of the thinner books ( <250 pages) but i cant be sure as I've spent three days going through these books now and cant locate it.

If it helps my 3.5 collection consists of : Exalted Deeds, Vile darkness and VD more archfiends, Complete adventurer, complete arcane, complete divine, complete warrior, draconomicon, DMG, PHB, Monster Manual, Expanded Psionics, Ghostwalk, and Unearthed Arcana.

And i also have other books, incase I'm wrong about it being a 3.5 thing...  Monster Manual 2, tome and blood, sword and fist, song and silence, oriental adventures, Masters of the wild druids grove and MotW barbariands druids and rangers, manual of the planes, fiend folio, Defenders of the faith, arms and equipment, and... uh..  the book of erotic fantasy.  =)

I know that its a long shot for someone to pin-point this as I'm having issues finding it with my books in front of me or with google...  but I appreciate any information or help on finding this ruling.

Comment: Welcome to site. Take the [tour]. The site's pretty good at finding things, but more information is always useful. Do you know if the product was Wizards of the Coast or third party? Can you remember anything else that was in the same book? Can you describe the cover? Do you know who wrote it? Was the book in color or monochrome? How much the book or the item cost? Don't *Yes/No* these questions, but edit your question to add details you *do* remember so the search can be narrowed from the 1,000s of *d20* products to the 100s or 10s. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This description fits to the Blood Ghoul template, Ghostwalk web enhancement p. 1-3.

> To create a blood ghoul, a vampire must get the target creature to
>   ingest some of his undead blood.

The template confers a rage-like ability:

> Ghoul Rage (Ex): By drawing upon the corrupt power within its body, a
>   blood ghoul can choose to enter a limited sort of rage. When this
>   ability is activated, the creature’s mouth froths with blood, and its
>   eyes turn red from increased blood flow. This ability works exactly
>   like a barbarian’s rage, except that the creature’s Strength and
>   Constitution scores each increase by only
>   +2, and the effect lasts for only 3 rounds, regardless of the blood ghoul’s Constitution modifier. There is no daily use limit for this
>   ability, but each use of ghoul rage subtracts one day from the
>   template’s remaining duration. Even animals with this template can
>   activate this ability of their own free will, and they tend to do so
>   whenever they enter combat.

But there is no mention of vials - I take it that was just your image of the process.

Comment: If it was a web enhancement, is it still available? A link would improve your answer (though I’ve already upvoted).

Comment: @KRyan The [page](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20030607a) for the Web enhancement exists, but the link to the Web enhancement proper leads nowhere.