# How does one gain vampiric powers without becoming a vampire?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races, character-templates

For example:

- a vampire feeds their blood a human in order to give them some of the vampires' powers.
- one gains some of the vampires' powers after surviving a fight with them
- one get cursed and receives some of the vampiric powers as the result

**How does one gain vampiric powers without becoming a vampire?** I am looking for a permanent solution, that wouldn't be lost in antimagic fields or by dispelling magic. Is there anything in *Dungeon and Dragons 3.5* or any other edition(it will be converted into 3.5 material) that could give those?

Dragon Magazine and Dungeon Adventures are also acceptable.

Comment: @Momonga-sama: Can you be clearer about what is off with the Blood Ghoul template?

Comment: Blood Ghoul fits the anwer only as the description. Rage ability, ability boons. None of the vampiric abilities. It is not the answer to the question, that I have asked.

Comment: Please calm down. I can see how that isn't a duplicate (you are asking _if_ there are ways, that question is about _where_ one way is), but as it stands, that question has the best answer you can get. Try editing this question to say what you're trying to find that Blood Ghoul has not, so that it becomes a clear "that is not the answer" for everyone.

Comment: Blood ghoul doesn't grant ANY vampiric power.  He gains just a feat, that happens to be a bonus feat for vampires. He gains some sort of Barbarian's rage, which has entirely NOTHING to do with any vampire. He gains scent, which has also NOTHING to do with any vampire. He gains ability boons, that one happens to be one of the vampire's ability boons. He doesn't gian any resistances, special attacks, special qualities. Nothing.

Comment: those ^^ would be good to somehow incorporate into the post. Please trust that others here are sincerely unclear as to the difference, and need your help understanding how your post is different from the one linked as duplicate. Nothing done can't be undone, this question could be reopened. But please assume good faith of everyone else on the site, don't shout, and try to work with people rather than against.

Comment: I've reopened this. Closing as duplicate is for questions which contain the exact same problem. If material at [What book describes consuming vials of vampire blood to pseudo-Rage?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72972) is coincidentally the only answer to this—different—question, then it should be used as part of an answer written up to explain that.

Comment: I don't think it meets your criteria as its effects are transitory, but the 7th-level Sor/Wiz spell *kiss of the vampire* [necro] (*Spell Compendium* 128-9) might be of interest. (If it *does* meet your criteria, feel free to add it to your answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both following templates doesn't change you to undead, however some turning undead might give you penalties.**

## Katane (template)

from Dragon #313 p. 62

> Cursed with a thirst for living blood and possessed of awful powers befitting creatures of the night, katanes are some of the more common half-undead. The human-like appearance and social behavior of vampires and their spawn result in ample opportunities for half-breed creation, and some vampires retain enough human sentiment to care for the child, improving the katane's chances of survival.
>
> Katanes are pale and slender, with jet-black hair and red, black, green, or yellow eyes. They have pronounced canines that extend for feeding and slightly pointed ears. Some of the less fortunate (those with a Charisma score of 7 or below) have batlike features.

## Half vampire(template)

from Libris Mortis p. 106

> In rare circumstances, a vampire that has recently consumed a
> significant quantity of blood gains the ability to breed successfully
> with living humanoids or monstrous humanoids, creating half-vampire
> offspring. Also, in the unusual case of a pregnant humanoid or
> monstrous humanoid who survives a vampire's blood drain attack, the
> child may be born "tainted" by the attacker's vampirism. Regardless of
> the origin, the children produced by such events are typically branded
> as outcasts, welcome neither among the living or the undead. A
> half-vampire is drawn to other living creatures, and feels far more
> comfortable when living in towns or cities. Still, half-vampires know
> that they must keep their identities secret or else risk the hatred
> and violence of others.
>
> Half-vampires are often physically attractive and persuasive. Their
> skin is pale, even ashen in color.
>
> Unlike their undead forebears, half-vampires enjoy the freedom (or
> curse) of pursuing any alignment, though most tend toward neutrality
> or evil. Those rare few good-aligned half-vampires often feel haunted
> by their heritage, sometimes working to undo the evil of their
> ancestry.

Comment: Okey, just stayed with their descriptions.

Comment: In particular there's reason to not post the templates in their entirety: we don't have the right to reproduce that material, and since doing so renders getting the book unnecessary for their usage, it's definitely not fair use.

Answer (score -2):

The closest I can find in RAW rules is a Vampire Spawn (which is, more basically, a weaker vampire)

> Create Spawn (Su) A humanoid or monstrous humanoid slain by a
>   vampire’s energy drain rises as a vampire spawn 1d4 days after burial.
>
> If the vampire instead drains the victim’s Constitution to 0 or lower,
>   the victim returns as a spawn if it had 4 or less HD and as a vampire
>   if it had 5 or more HD. In either case, the new vampire or spawn is
>   under the command of the vampire that created it and remains enslaved
>   until its master’s destruction. At any given time a vampire may have
>   enslaved spawn totaling no more than twice its own Hit Dice; any spawn
>   it creates that would exceed this limit are created as free-willed
>   vampires or vampire spawn. A vampire that is enslaved may create and
>   enslave spawn of its own, so a master vampire can control a number of
>   lesser vampires in this fashion. A vampire may voluntarily free an
>   enslaved spawn in order to enslave a new spawn, but once freed, a
>   vampire or vampire spawn cannot be enslaved again.

But the beauty of DnD is RULE 0: the DM makes the rules.

If you can create a fair/balanced system, with enough flavor, your DM could allow it.